# SQL: How to make a conditional COUNT and SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, sum

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id    | letter   | date   
--------------------------------
1     | A        | 2011-01-01
2     | A        | 2011-04-01
3     | A        | 2011-04-01
4     | B        | 2011-01-01
5     | B        | 2011-01-01 
6     | B        | 2011-01-01
```

I would like to make a count of the rows broken down by letter and date, *and* sum the count of all the *previous* dates. every letter should have a row to every date of the table (ie. letter B doesn't have a 2011-04-01 date, but still appears in the result)

The resulting table would look like this

```
letter| date           | total  
--------------------------------
A     | 2011-01-01     | 1
A     | 2011-04-01     | 3
B     | 2011-01-01     | 3 
B     | 2011-04-01     | 3
```

How to achieve this in a SQL query? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What sense to select date which belongs to another letter? (in your case you select 2011-02-04 for B)

Comment: There is no record for `B` on 4/1. Where is that row coming from?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! My bad for not making it more explicit that it was for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**
I didn't notice it was mysql, which doesn't support CTE.  You may be able to define temporary tables to use this.

---

This is an interesting problem.  You kind of need to join all letters with all dates and then count the preceding rows.  If you weren't concerned with having rows for letters that have a count of 0 for the dates, you could probably just do something like this:

```
SELECT letter, date, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM tbl tbl2 
     WHERE tbl2.letter = tbl1.letter
        AND tbl2.date <= tbl1.date) AS total
FROM tbl
ORDER BY date, letter
```

---

/*deleted CTE solution*/

---

**Solution without CTE**

```
SELECT tblDates.[date], tblLetters.letter, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM tblData tbl2
     WHERE tbl2.letter = tblLetters.letter
        AND tbl2.[date] <= tblDates.[date]) AS total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [date] FROM tblData) tblDates
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT letter FROM tblData) tblLetters
ORDER BY tblDates.[date], tblLetters.letter
```

Comment: Ugh... missed that it was mysql.

Comment: A note - `inner join ... on 1=1` can be replaced with `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @sam dehaan Thanks for the tip on the cross join.  I updated the answer.

Comment: No problem. I only learned of the keyword the other day when someone informed me here on SO, figured I could pay it forward.

Comment: Great answer. However there is one tweak necessary to make it perfect: change the operator to smaller *and* equal on that line : AND tbl2.[date] < tblDates.[date]) AS total

Comment: Thanks, @DavidD, I added that in the first query, but forgot to do it in the second.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

The  requirement

> every letter should have a row to every date of the table

requires a cross join of the distinct dates and letters. Once you do that its pretty straight forward

```
SELECT letterdate.letter, 
       letterdate.DATE, 
       COUNT(yt.id) total 
FROM   (SELECT letter, 
               date 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT DATE 
                FROM   yourtable) dates, 
               (SELECT DISTINCT letter 
                FROM   yourtable) letter) letterdate 
       LEFT JOIN yourtable yt 
         ON letterdate.letter = yt.letter 
            AND yt.DATE < yt.letter 
GROUP  BY letterdate.letter, 
          letterdate.DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on the previous:

```
    declare @table1 table (id int, letter char, date smalldatetime)
    insert into @table1 values (1, 'A', '1/1/2011')
    insert into @table1 values (2, 'A', '4/1/2011')
    insert into @table1 values (3, 'A', '4/1/2011')
    insert into @table1 values (4, 'B', '1/1/2011')
    insert into @table1 values (5, 'B', '1/1/2011')
    insert into @table1 values (6, 'B', '1/1/2011')


    select b.letter, b.date, count(0) AS count_ 
    from (
        select distinct letter, a.date from @table1
        cross join (select distinct date from @table1 ) a 
            ) b     
    join @table1 t1
    on t1.letter = b.letter
    and t1.date <= b.date       
    group by b.letter, b.date
    order by b.letter
```